# Ben's numbers - Digital Numbers

Tags: mathematics

Ben created a new type of number called 'a digital number'.
(He's bad at naming things.)

When a number equals the sum of all its digits times its position in the given set (1 to 1000), it is called 'a digital number'.

For example, 1 is a 'digital number', because: 1 * (1st position) = 1

423 is *not* a 'digital number', because: (4+2+3) * (423rd position) = 3807

**How many 'digital' numbers are there inside the given set 1 to 1000?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A number's position is equal to its value, so you're just asking for the numbers where the digital sum is 1. That would be 1, 10, 100, and 1000, so there are four.

Comment: I think he means that, for a number that's the concatenation of digits A, B, C, and D, in this order, it's a digital number, if and only if A + 2B + 3C + 4D.

Comment: @Chill: He said "sum of all its digits times *its* position in the given *set*", not "sum of all the digits times *their* position in the given *number*".

Comment: Ah, my bad. Must have misread the question. Oh well, at least gave me a reason to unrust my Javascript a bit.

Comment: Why is 1000 excluded?

Comment: @Ian: Because I read "1 to 1000" and thought "1 to 999" for some reason.

Comment: Man, why do you forget `>!`?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ: Spoiler tags are not required. I find spoiler formatting annoying, so I prefer to omit it when I can't be bothered.

Comment: @Deusovi Of course, but that might ruin someone's day.. just sayin'. Good job on the answer though +1

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**: Aparently I misunderstood this be question.
Left here for historical reasons.
The numbers are:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19

Proof:

> 1000 is not a digital number
>  Let's consider the 3 digit number ABC where A is not 0.
>  So $100*A + 10 * B + C = 1*A + 2*B+3*C$
>  this becomes $99*A = 2*C - 8*B$
>  Since A B and C are digits, the min value for $99*A$ is 99 and the max value for $2*C - 8*B$ is 18 ($2*9-8*0$).  So this cannot be.
>  Conclusion there are no 3 digit numbers like that.
>
>  Let's consider the 2 digit number $AB$.
>  So $10*A + B = 1*A+2*B$
>  This becomes $9*A = B$
>  Since A and B are digits, the only possible values are $A=1, B=9$. So $AB = 19$.
>
>  Let's consider the 1 digit number A.
>  So $A = 1*A$.
>  this is true for every number between 1 and 9 (even between 0 and 9).

Option 2:

> let x be the number and s the sum of all it's digits
>  So $s *x = x$
>  This means $x = 0$ or $s=1$.
>  Since the set is from 1 to 1000, $x=0$ is not an option.
>  So $s = 1$.
>  The only numbers that satisfy this are $1, 10, 100, 1000$

Comment: You made the same mistake I had bub, he said the digit sum in relation to position in the set, not position in the actual number.

Comment: @ChillFruit. If 2 people made the same mistake it means the question was not clear. Wouldn't you say that?

Comment: He said "sum of all its digits times **its** position in the given **set**", not "sum of all the digits times **their** position in the given **number**".

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it's unclear; I'm known for reading things far too fast and making misunderstandings '-_-.

Comment: I agree that the question was unclear. This is because the example provided was 1 * 1 = 1, which tells us exactly nothing about the intended origins of the numbers involved. I added an extra example in hopes that it either helps to explain the puzzle *or* cause the puzzle creator to reword it to get the intended puzzle

Comment: Congratulations, Marius, you have solved 3 puzzles in one!
Puzzle 1 -- Just what puzzle is being posed? This is a puzzle-within-a-puzzle for *every* puzzle.
Puzzle 2 -- Your Option 1,
            which must be the original intent here,
            before non-OPs' edits.
Puzzle 3 -- Your Option 2, which seems to have resulted
            from an accidental choice of words
            in the original puzzle statement.
I hope that others realize this too and ^vote your answer(s) accordingly.

Comment: @hmmn: No, the puzzle statement was fairly clear. "Sum of all digits times its position in the given set" is what was asked.

Comment: @humn, not that I'm complaining, but why did I get a bounty for this?

Comment: Guess the bounty's blurb got lost when it was delivered, Marius, but it basically repeated my comment here about your having solved 3 puzzles in one and receiving little credit for it. (I often wish I could beat the one-vote limit and finally realized how a bounty can amount to that.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this the lazymans way,

(what follows is this is python code)

```
def addDigits(x):
   l = 0
   for char in str(x):
        l += int(char)
   return l

def offset(start, x):
    return x-(start-1)
def findDigitalNumbers(x,y):
    DNumbers = []
    for num in range(x,y+1):
        if( (addDigits(num) * offset(x, num))== num):
            print(num)
            DNumbers.append(num)
    return DNumbers
```

Using this i found that the numbers are

> 1, 10, 100, 1000